# Record streaming audio to FLAC format with vlc

Tags: vlc

I have a question, I am trying to record audio from a radio stream and extract the audio in FLAC format with the following characteristics:

Channel: Mono
Sample rate: 16000
Bite rate: 320 or 128

I have the following vlc expression that I am using, does it correspond to my requirements above? And am I using the correct Audio codecs and Muxers?

```
"--sout=#transcode{acodec=flac,ab=320,channels=1,samplerate=16000}:std{access=file,mux=flac,dst='example.flac'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct audio codec `acodec=flac` but the `mux` should either be `raw` or `ogg` (`mux=raw` or `mux=ogg`). `flac` is the accepted audio codec for `ogg` container format and is thus used with it mostly.

For more details, look at this example:
[Extracting audio in FLAC format](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Extract_audio/#Extracting_audio_in_FLAC_format)

And the [supported VLC Muxers](https://wiki.videolan.org/Codec/#Muxers)